# Calculating time complexity of recursive functions under constraints

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

The function below is a recursive approach for finding the number of strings of a given length under given constraints. Can anyone please explain how to calculate the time complexity in a clear manner. From what I understand is that at each step in a recursion tree, no of calls made by a node is either 2 or 3. So is the upper bound 3^n , i.e. , O(3^n)?.

```
int countStr(string str, int n, int bCount, int cCount)
{  
    if (str.length() == n)
      return 1;

    int result = 0 ;
      result += countStr(str+'a', n, bCount, 0);

    if (bCount == 0)
      result += countStr(str+'b', n, 1, 0);

    if (cCount < 2)
      result += countStr(str+'c', n, bCount, cCount+1);

    return result ;
}
main()
{    
    int n = 3 ;
    cout << countStr("", n, 0, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not really clear to my what this method is doing and how it is supposed to be called. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: it seems like the output only depends on `n,bCount,cCount` and the size of `str` but not the contents of `str`. The first thing I would do is to is change the method to not pass the string, but only its length, because imho appending the `a`s, `b`s and `c`s only distracts from what is really going on

Comment: I have updated the question. My initial call to the function is with empty string. So this won't recurse infinitely.

Comment: `bCount` and `cCount` are always `0` on the first call?

Comment: Yes. The initial call will have both the values as 0.